# How Convert Complex Json String to Object .?

Tags: java, json, gson

I wanna convert Json String to Object class. I tried several times with several codes but its gave me a error. Also now its gives **null** for list

Infor are below

Here is my Json

```
    {
    "customer": {
        "msisdn": "123456789",
        "imsi": "0987654321",
        "title": "Mr",
        "firstName": "Bilbo",
        "lastName": "Baggins",
        "dob": "21/10/2006",
        "identificationType": "PP",
        "identificationNumber": "PP12345DC",
        "onBehalfOf": "my_Merchant",
        "purchaseCategoryCode": "Game",
        "accountType": "Postpaid",
        "ownerType": "Paymaster",
        "status": "Confirmed",
        "requestIdentifier": "REQ12345678",
        "responseIdentifier": "RES12345678",
        "address": {
            "line1": "Bag End",
            "line2": "",
            "line3": "",
            "city": "The Shire",
            "country": "Middle Earth"
        },
        "additionalInfo ": [{
            "tag": "creditLimit",
            "value": "2500"
        }, {
            "tag": "creditLimit",
            "value": "2500"
        }],
        "resourceURL": "http://google.com/abc/123"
    }
}
```

Here is my Main class code

```
public class TestJsonDemo{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        String testString="{\r\n" + 
                "   \"customer\": {\r\n" + 
                "       \"msisdn\": \"123456789\",\r\n" + 
                "       \"imsi\": \"0987654321\",\r\n" + 
                "       \"title\": \"Mr\",\r\n" + 
                "       \"firstName\": \"Bilbo\",\r\n" + 
                "       \"lastName\": \"Baggins\",\r\n" + 
                "       \"dob\": \"21/10/2006\",\r\n" + 
                "       \"identificationType\": \"PP\",\r\n" + 
                "       \"identificationNumber\": \"PP12345DC\",\r\n" + 
                "       \"onBehalfOf\": \"my_Merchant\",\r\n" + 
                "       \"purchaseCategoryCode\": \"Game\",\r\n" + 
                "       \"accountType\": \"Postpaid\",\r\n" + 
                "       \"ownerType\": \"Paymaster\",\r\n" + 
                "       \"status\": \"Confirmed\",\r\n" + 
                "       \"requestIdentifier\": \"REQ12345678\",\r\n" + 
                "       \"responseIdentifier\": \"RES12345678\",\r\n" + 
                "       \"address\": {\r\n" + 
                "           \"line1\": \"Bag End\",\r\n" + 
                "           \"line2\": \"\",\r\n" + 
                "           \"line3\": \"\",\r\n" + 
                "           \"city\": \"The Shire\",\r\n" + 
                "           \"country\": \"Middle Earth\"\r\n" + 
                "       },\r\n" + 
                "       \"additionalInfo \": [{\r\n" + 
                "           \"tag\": \"creditLimit\",\r\n" + 
                "           \"value\": \"2500\"\r\n" + 
                "       }, {\r\n" + 
                "           \"tag\": \"creditLimit\",\r\n" + 
                "           \"value\": \"2500\"\r\n" + 
                "       }],\r\n" + 
                "       \"resourceURL\": \"http://google.com/abc/123\"\r\n" + 
                "   }\r\n" + 
                "}";

        Gson gson=new Gson();
        CustomerInfo customerInfo = gson.fromJson(testString, CustomerInfo.class);
        System.out.println(customerInfo);
    }
}
```

Here is my out

```
ClassPojo [customer = ClassPojo [lastName = Baggins, additionalInfo  = null, resourceURL = http://google.com/abc/123, status = Confirmed, msisdn = 123456789, ownerType = Paymaster, identificationType = PP, onBehalfOf = my_Merchant, responseIdentifier = RES12345678, requestIdentifier = REQ12345678, title = Mr, address = ClassPojo [line1 = Bag End, line3 = , country = Middle Earth, city = The Shire, line2 = ], dob = 21/10/2006, purchaseCategoryCode = Game, accountType = Postpaid, imsi = 0987654321, firstName = Bilbo, identificationNumber = PP12345DC]]
```

But its  **additionalInfo  = null** :-(

How to resolve this one.?

Here with I'll attach remaining POJO classes too

Thanks

```
class CustomerInfo {
    private Customer customer;

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassPojo [customer = " + customer + "]";
    }
}

class Customer {
    private String lastName;

    private AdditionalInfo[] additionalInfo;

    private String resourceURL;

    private String status;

    private String msisdn;

    private String ownerType;

    private String identificationType;

    private String onBehalfOf;

    private String responseIdentifier;

    private String requestIdentifier;

    private String title;

    private Address address;

    private String dob;

    private String purchaseCategoryCode;

    private String accountType;

    private String imsi;

    private String firstName;

    private String identificationNumber;

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public AdditionalInfo[] getAdditionalInfo() {
        return additionalInfo;
    }

    public void setAdditionalInfo(AdditionalInfo[] additionalInfo) {
        this.additionalInfo = additionalInfo;
    }

    public String getResourceURL() {
        return resourceURL;
    }

    public void setResourceURL(String resourceURL) {
        this.resourceURL = resourceURL;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMsisdn() {
        return msisdn;
    }

    public void setMsisdn(String msisdn) {
        this.msisdn = msisdn;
    }

    public String getOwnerType() {
        return ownerType;
    }

    public void setOwnerType(String ownerType) {
        this.ownerType = ownerType;
    }

    public String getIdentificationType() {
        return identificationType;
    }

    public void setIdentificationType(String identificationType) {
        this.identificationType = identificationType;
    }

    public String getOnBehalfOf() {
        return onBehalfOf;
    }

    public void setOnBehalfOf(String onBehalfOf) {
        this.onBehalfOf = onBehalfOf;
    }

    public String getResponseIdentifier() {
        return responseIdentifier;
    }

    public void setResponseIdentifier(String responseIdentifier) {
        this.responseIdentifier = responseIdentifier;
    }

    public String getRequestIdentifier() {
        return requestIdentifier;
    }

    public void setRequestIdentifier(String requestIdentifier) {
        this.requestIdentifier = requestIdentifier;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getPurchaseCategoryCode() {
        return purchaseCategoryCode;
    }

    public void setPurchaseCategoryCode(String purchaseCategoryCode) {
        this.purchaseCategoryCode = purchaseCategoryCode;
    }

    public String getAccountType() {
        return accountType;
    }

    public void setAccountType(String accountType) {
        this.accountType = accountType;
    }

    public String getImsi() {
        return imsi;
    }

    public void setImsi(String imsi) {
        this.imsi = imsi;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getIdentificationNumber() {
        return identificationNumber;
    }

    public void setIdentificationNumber(String identificationNumber) {
        this.identificationNumber = identificationNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassPojo [lastName = " + lastName + ", additionalInfo  = "
                + additionalInfo + ", resourceURL = " + resourceURL
                + ", status = " + status + ", msisdn = " + msisdn
                + ", ownerType = " + ownerType + ", identificationType = "
                + identificationType + ", onBehalfOf = " + onBehalfOf
                + ", responseIdentifier = " + responseIdentifier
                + ", requestIdentifier = " + requestIdentifier + ", title = "
                + title + ", address = " + address + ", dob = " + dob
                + ", purchaseCategoryCode = " + purchaseCategoryCode
                + ", accountType = " + accountType + ", imsi = " + imsi
                + ", firstName = " + firstName + ", identificationNumber = "
                + identificationNumber + "]";
    }
}

class AdditionalInfo {
    private String tag;

    private String value;

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassPojo [tag = " + tag + ", value = " + value + "]";
    }
}

class Address {
    private String line1;

    private String line3;

    private String country;

    private String city;

    private String line2;

    public String getLine1() {
        return line1;
    }

    public void setLine1(String line1) {
        this.line1 = line1;
    }

    public String getLine3() {
        return line3;
    }

    public void setLine3(String line3) {
        this.line3 = line3;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getLine2() {
        return line2;
    }

    public void setLine2(String line2) {
        this.line2 = line2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassPojo [line1 = " + line1 + ", line3 = " + line3
                + ", country = " + country + ", city = " + city + ", line2 = "
                + line2 + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use jackson library for this.

Comment: Have you tried using some Collection for AdditionalInfo instead of array? For instance `List<AdditionalInfo> additionalInfo;`? I have used Gson library before and that was the problem AFAIR.

Comment: Provide AdditionalInfo class also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small mistake in your JSON file, if you check the name "additionalInfo" you have and extra space at the end and that make it fails

```
"additionalInfo "
```

Change to

```
"additionalInfo"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change all your class to public (including your additionalinfo. It may help.

As I know some of JSON parser do not like private class thus they simply ignore it

Answer (score 1):

I would use Jackson instead of Gson, but this is a matter of taste.
First I would configure the reader (jackson/gson) to be tolerant, meaning the reader should not fail on missing or unknown properties in your json.
ref:[TolerantReader](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TolerantReader.html)

Additionally I would try to use Collections (ArrayList in your case) over Arrays and initialize them as empty, to avoid Nullpointer exceptions.

Also, you have a lot of Strings in your model, I would choose the types more wisely.

And while typing @cralfaro already got the point I was going to make now :D
To spot such typos earlier, may remove `\r` and `\n` from your `testString`.